# Помогите понять Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger2, inversion-of-control

Добрый день уважаемые специалисты. Хочу изучить библиотеку Dagger2, раньше с подобным ничем дело не имел, но учиться нужно. Прошу помочь переделать данный код из моего примера в код, работающий с помощью Dagger2 с минимальными его фишками(simple example). В интернете множество примеров, но они сходу заваливают кучей своих аннотаций, хочется разобраться в самых основах и постепенно прибавлять знания в этом вопросе, заранее благодарен за помощь.
Собственно сам код:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// создаем объекты для инжектирования в конструктор StartLogger
Logger logger = new Logger("logger1&logmessage", "logdata");
Logger2 logger2 = new Logger2("logger2&logdata");
// Создаем StartLogger и инжектируем объекты в его конструктор.
StartLogger startLoger = new StartLogger(logger, logger2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startLoger.sendLog();
   }
}
```

Класс в который инжектируем созданные в главном классе приложения объекты

```
public class StartLogger {
// создаем переменные типа
Logger logger;
Logger2 logger2;

public StartLogger(Logger logger, Logger2 logger2){
    this.logger = logger;
    this.logger2 = logger2;
}
public void sendLog(){
    logger.toWork();
    logger2.toWork();
}
}
```

Первый логгер

```
import android.util.Log;
public class Logger {

private String logMessage;
private String logData;

public Logger(String logMessage, String logData)
{
    this.logMessage = logMessage;
    this.logData = logData;
}
public void toWork(){
    Log.d(logMessage, logData);
}
}
```

Второй логгер

```
import android.util.Log;
public class Logger2 {

private String logData;
public Logger2(String logData){
    this.logData = logData;
}
public void toWork(){
    Log.d("LOG2", logData);
}
}
```

Comment: не вижу в коде попыток применить даггер. почитайте статьи на хабре. аннотации это просто аннотации, ничего страшного в них нет

Comment: Да, читал, здесь и нет попыток его применить. Хотелось бы чтобы человек в теме подсказал как его применить в данном случае. Это было б отправной точкой.

Comment: отправная точка - создать компоненту и заинжектить апликейшн. для этого надо почитать статьи. объяснять как работает даггер это обширная тема

Comment: Вот https://m.habr.com/post/345372/    серия статей , прочтите с первой до 4 и увидите, что точно такой же код как у вас в этой статье с применением даггер 2